# prove whether the subspace $M \subset C[0,1]$ (under $d_1$) consisting of all $x \in C[0,1]$ such that $x(0) = 1$ is closed or not

Tags: functional-analysis

prove whether the subspace $M \subset C[0,1]$ (under $d_1$) consisting of all $x \in C[0,1]$ such that $x(0) = 1$ is closed or not

$d_1 (x,y)= \int \left|x(t)-y(t)\right| \, dt$

now I know that if $M$ is closed, it means that for any $x_n \to x$ belongs to $C$, the $x$ must belongs to $M$.
But I don't know how to prove it or refute it

Thanks

Comment: Your $d_1$ is not a metric. Did you mean $d_1(x,y)=\int |x(t)-y(t))|\,dt$?

Comment: @Joshua Tilley
Yeah! I am sorry i made a mistake

Comment: $f_n(x)=1-nx$ for $x \leq \frac  1n,0$ for $x>\frac 1n$. $\int |f_n-0|\to 0$.

Comment: @geetha290krm  OH！THX! I always get stuck with these constructed sequences

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @geetha290krm
we can find that ,there exists an xn = 1−nt for t ≤ 1/n，it's limit is x = 0
it's obvious that x does not belong to M